# Java RegEx for parsing the quoted arguments

Tags: java, regex, arguments, pattern-matching, command-line-arguments

Need a Java regex pattern for the following scenario:

**Case 1:**

Input string:

```
"a"
```

Matches:

```
a
```

**Case 2:**

Input string:

```
"a b"
```

Matches:

```
a b
```

**Case 3:**

Input string:

```
"aA Bb" cCc 123 4 5 6 7xy "\"z9" "\"z9$^"
```

Matches:

```
aA Bb
cCc
123
4
5
6
7xy
"z9
"z9$^
```

**Case 4:**

Input string:

```
"a b c
```

Matches:

```
None - since the quotes are unbalanced, hence pattern match fails.
```

**Case 5:**

Input string:

```
"a b" "c
```

Matches:

```
None - since the quotes are unbalanced, hence pattern match fails.
```

**Case 6:**

Input string:

```
"a b" p q r "x y z"
```

Matches:

```
a b
p 
q 
r
x y z
```

**Case 7:**

Input string:

```
"a b" p q r "x y \"z\""
```

Matches:

```
a b
p 
q
r
x y "z"
```

**Case 8:**

Input string:

```
"a b" p q r "x \"y \"z\""
```

Matches:

```
a b
p 
q 
r
x "y "z"
```

And of course, the simplest one:

**Case 9:**

Input string:

```
a b
```

Matches:

```
a
b
```

Tried using a pattern, but it doesn't seem to match all above cases.

```
public List<String> parseArgs(String argStr) {
    List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
    String pattern = "\\s*(\"[^\"]+\"|[^\\s\"]+)";
    Pattern quotedParamPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = quotedParamPattern.matcher(argStr);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String param = matcher.group();
            System.out.println(param);
            params.add(param);
    }
    return params;
}

public void test(String argStr) {
    String[] testStrings = new String[]{"a", "a b", "a b \"c\"", "a b \"c"};
    for(String s: testStrings){
        parseArgs(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be solved but you need to show some effort of solving it. At least place all the example input strings in an array of String (`String[]`) and place that Java code here.

Comment: @anubhava Added the Java code and a few input strings.

Comment: I'm guessing your actual strings will be more than just single lowercase letters.  Do they need to contain capital letters, numbers, special characters, etc?  Is there a limit to how long they should be?

Comment: @CAustin There may be capital letters, numbers, special characters and so on, but there's no limit as such.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want with this but I'm sure the answer is way before you arrive to this.

Comment: @Tuga I'm building a command-line application framework where I need to interpret a command and its arguments. This effort is basically to parse out every valid argument from a given command string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have written a class "CLIParser" which will give you the result.

```
//instantiate the CLIParser 

CLIParser parser = new CLIParser("\"a b\" p q r \"x y z\"");

//call the method getTokens which gives you the result.

ArrayList<String> resultTokens = parser.getTokens();


###################CLI Parser Class definition#################################

class CLIParser {
    private String cmdString;

    public CLIParser(String cmdString) {
        this.cmdString = cmdString;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTokens() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> finalTokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<StringBuffer> tokens = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
    char inArray[] = this.cmdString.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer token = new StringBuffer();
    int valid = checkIfTheStringIsValid(inArray);
    if (valid == -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= inArray.length; i++) {

            if (i != inArray.length) {
                if ((inArray[i] != ' ') && (inArray[i] != '"')) {
                    token.append(inArray[i]);
                }

                if ((inArray[i] == '"') && (inArray[i - 1] != '\\')) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    while (checkIfLastQuote(inArray, i)) {
                        token.append(inArray[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (i == inArray.length) {
                tokens.add(token);
                token = new StringBuffer();
            } else if (inArray[i] == ' ' && inArray[i] != '"') {
                tokens.add(token);
                token = new StringBuffer();
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new InvalidCommandException(
                "Invalid command. Couldn't identify sequence at position "
                        + valid);
    }
    for(StringBuffer tok:tokens){
        finalTokens.add(tok.toString());
    }
    return finalTokens;
}

private static int checkIfTheStringIsValid(char[] inArray) {
    Stack myStack = new Stack<Character>();
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inArray.length; i++) {
        if (inArray[i] == '"' && inArray[i - 1] != '\\') {
            pos = i;
            if (myStack.isEmpty())
                myStack.push(inArray[i]);
            else
                myStack.pop();
        }
    }
    if (myStack.isEmpty())
        return -1;
    else
        return pos;
}

private static boolean checkIfLastQuote(char inArray[], int i) {
    if (inArray[i] == '"') {
        if (inArray[i - 1] == '\\') {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the straight way to solve with regex.

But you can replace the inner escape sequences with some unique keyword, then you can match your strings with regex.

```
String[] testStrings = new String[]{
         "a", "a b", "a b \"c\"", "a b \"c", "\"a b\" p q r \"x y z\""};
Pattern parsingPattern = Pattern.compile("(\".*?\")|( [^ ^\"]+)");
for(String s: testStrings) {
   s=s.replace("(?<!\\)\\"","@@@");
}
for(String s: testStrings) {
    List<String> params = null;
    int count = StringUtils.countMatches(s, "\"");
    if(count%2==0){
    params = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = parsePattern.matcher(s); 
    while (matcher.find())
        params.add( matcher.group(1) != null ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2));
   }
}
```

Once you get the matches, you can replace your unique identifier with actual keyword..

I haven't tested the code snippet, but I hope you can do some minor tweaks to make it work.

Comment: Seems like a fair solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

`("\S+?(?: \S+?)*"|\S+?)`

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/fA5hN0

Just run a global match and return `\1`. Each capture group that gets returned should contain what you want.

Comment: Is there a Java regex string available cuz' the above pattern needs escaping slashes and quotes and even when escaped, it doesn't seem to work for all cases. Tried for this input string: "a b" p q r "x y \"z\""

Answer (score 0):

To get you started you can use this Java regex based code:

```
public List<String> parseArgs(String argStr, Pattern validPattern, Pattern parsePattern) {
    List<String> params = null;
    if (validPattern.matcher(argStr).matches()) {
        params = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher matcher = parsePattern.matcher(argStr); 
        while (matcher.find())
            params.add( matcher.group(1) != null ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2));
    }
    return params;
}

public void parseIt() {
    Pattern validatePattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$).*$");
    Pattern parsingPattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|(\\w+)");

    String[] testStrings = new String[]{
             "a", "a b", "a b \"c\"", "a b \"c", "\"a b\" p q r \"x y z\""};
    for(String s: testStrings) {
        List<String> parsedList = parseArgs(s, validatePattern, parsingPattern);
        System.out.printf("input: %-30s :: parsed: %s%n", s, parsedList);
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
input: a                              :: parsed: [a]
input: a b                            :: parsed: [a, b]
input: a b "c"                        :: parsed: [a, b, c]
input: a b "c                         :: parsed: null
input: "a b" p q r "x y z"            :: parsed: [a b, p, q, r, x y z]
```

**PS:** Though I have noticed you latest edits where you have added nested quotes also, this answer needs to be enhanced for that.

Comment: This seems to work for most cases. But I'm trying to extract the strings in which there are escaped quotes as well. Tried with this: "aA Bb" cCc 123 4 5 6 7xy "\"z9" "\"z9$^" This is supposed to give me "z9 as 8th argument and "z9$^ as the 9th. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I made a note of it since i didn't notice escaped/nested quotes in your question earlier.

Comment: What regular expression would match all the above cases?

Comment: There is no end to escaping actually. Even backslash can be escaped. How are you getting this input?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's the way it's supposed to work for the app I'm building. Even this is valid "aA Bb" cCc 123 4 5 6 7xy "\"\\z9" "\"z9$^". And the strings are being read from stdin.

Comment: In that case I would suggest stop looking at regex solution and build a parser yourself.

Comment: But isn't the regex more powerful than a parser? Cuz' parsing seems a bit costly operation for me since there will be enormous amounts of commands with numerous args being issued simultaneously.

Comment: Yes it might be costly but it will be more accurate also. Regex is for regular text not for irregular cases like you are trying to handle.